# In Japanese, what’s the difference between “Tonari ni” (となりに) and “Tsugi” (つぎ)? When would you use one over the other?

Tags: words

In Japanese, what’s the difference between “[Tonari ni](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/index.cfm?j=Tonari)” (となりに) and “[Tsugi](https://www.tanoshiijapanese.com/dictionary/index.cfm?j=Tsugi)” (つぎ)? Both mean “next”, but when would you use one over the other?

Please explain by referring to the following examples:

```
Tsugi no tōri = Next street
Tsugi no tsugi no tōri. = The street after the next.
Eigakan wa dono tōri ni arimasu ka. = What street is the movie theater on?
eki no tonari = Next to station
Hoteru wa eki no tonari desu. = The hotel is next to the train station.
```

Please note I am a beginner and would appreciate simplified explanations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

となり means "adjacent to". つぎ means "next in sequence".

For example, if you're talking about the bakery next door to your shop you would use となり. It doesn't matter if the shop is to the left or right of your shop; it is simply adjacent to it.

If you're walking down the street looking for something there is an order implied and the next shop is the one which follows on in sequence from where you are now. So つぎ would be appropriate.

Looking at it another way I guess となり means "next to" whereas つぎ just means "next".

Comment: となり also means "neighbor".

Answer (score 5):

隣{となり}に or 隣{となり}の pertains to a location (similar to 近{ちか}く) for if something is *directly next to* something else. For example the building next door.

次{つぎ} pertains to a sequence of events such as the next stop on a bus or train or the next page on a website. 次{つぎ}の次{つぎ} is the one after next (next of the next) which is also often used in Japan.